# PHP - Count files

Tags: php

I'm trying to count all files within a folder. This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php  
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("myfolder/mysubdolder");
foreach($dir as $file ){ $x += (isImage($file)) ? 1 : 0;}
?>
```

It returns this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function isImage() in C:...

What's wroing with my code?
Thanks
Uli

Comment: What's `isImage()`? Maybe you are confusing with `is_file()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php  
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("myfolder/mysubdolder");
foreach($dir as $file ){ $x += ($file->isFile()) ? 1 : 0;}
?>
```

have a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isfile.php

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you're calling a function (`isImage`), which you haven't defined. Incidentally, pretty much what the error message says.

You can implement such a function in many ways, but the simplest is to use `getimagesize`, which will raise a warning and return false, if you use it on a non-image. So:

```
function isImage($file) {
  return !! @getimagesize($file);
}
```

(Of course, that's assuming you only want to count images, which I kind of deduct from your code that you want. If you want to count all files, you increment the counter without any checks, on each loop.)

Answer (score 3):

If all the files are of a certain type, why not try this?

```
$directory = "../images/team/harry/";

if (glob($directory . "*.jpg") != false) {
 $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.jpg"));
} else { $filecount = 0; }
```

Comment: suggestion: the `glob()` is executed 2 times identically, which it can be simplified.

Comment: Yes. Shorter is: `$filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.jpg") ?: []);`

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following instead:

```
<?php  
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("myfolder/mysubfolder");
foreach($dir as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        $x++;
    }
}
?>
```

In my opinion this is much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<?php  
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator("myfolder/mysubdolder");
    foreach($dir as $file ){
        $x += (is_file($file)) ? 1 : 0;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$directory = 'templates';
$files = scandir($directory);
foreach($files as $value){
   if($value!='.' and $value!='..'){
      $numTemplates++;
   }
}
echo $numTemplates;
```

The method above is another alternative if you don't like DirectoryIterator and you don't want to include the hidden '.' and '..' folders.